# How to stop Firebase auth handled backend from carrying on to other browsers / sessions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, heroku, firebase-authentication

I'm in the process of creating an authentication based web app. It works fine when only one session is running, but if a user on another session is logged in, it carries through to all sessions allowing everyone to see that user's information and use their permissions.

I've determined that this is because I handle all of my authentication backend from this post:
[Firebase Auth : User session carried to different browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54529773/firebase-auth-user-session-carried-to-different-browser)

But I'd like to know whether there are any fixes without having to handle anything client-side. The post above doesn't give any fixes or advice.

This is the sign in route:

```
app.post('/postSignIn', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  let password = req.body.password;
  let email = req.body.email;
  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  if (user) {
    //TODO: Show user info is correct and redirect
    success = "You're already logged in!";
    res.render('login', {
      success: success
    })
  } else {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorMessage)
        res.render('login', {
          error: errorMessage
        })
      })
      .then(

      ).catch(
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            success = "You're logged in!";
            res.render('login', {
              success: success
            })
          } else {
            res.render('login', {
              error: errorMessage
            })
          }
        })
      );
  }
})
```

And here is an example of how the auth states are checked:

```
app.get('/makeThing', function(req, res) {
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
    res.render('makeThing')

  } else {
    res.render('things', {
      error: 'Login first.',
      things: things,
    })

  }
});
```

I thought this would handle different sessions, but it doesn't and `firebase.auth().currentUser` is remembered for all sessions, so if one user is logged in, all other sessions are logged into their account. It would be great if someone could describe either a front end or backend solution including a fix using something like Passport or Auth0.

The app is also being hosted on Heroku, so any fixes through there, such as running a different instance per user, would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is having the same problem, use cookies! After researching for a while I determined that it was the best solution.

This overflow page does a good job of explaining how to use them.
[How to set cookie in node js using express framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209145/how-to-set-cookie-in-node-js-using-express-framework][1])

This works because cookies are handled client side. I would recommend setting the cookies on log in and checking the current auth state through them instead of the Firebase current user functions. It worked for me!